# Named Parameters in Laravel view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

**[Solution at the bottom]**

I want to generate a link in a blade template to my controller action and passing two parameters. But Laravel throws always

> preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while
>   replacement is an array

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/projects/{project_id}/canals/{canal_id}/damages', array('as' => 'listDamages', 'uses' => 'DamageController@listDamages'));
```

**DamageController.php**

```
public function listDamages($project_id, $canal_id){
        $damages = Canal::find($canal_id)->damages;
        $canal = Canal::find($canal_id);
        $project = Project::find($project_id);
        return View::make('damages.list',array('damages' => $damages, 'canal' => $canal, 'project' => $project));
    }
```

**view.blade.php**

```
/* Values are:
$project->id = 71;
$canal->id = 5103;
*/

{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('listDamages',array('project_id' => $project->id,'canal_id' => $canal->id)), 'method' => 'get', 'class' =>'action-form')) }}
<button type="submit" href="{{ route('listDamages',array('project_id' => $project->id,'canal_id' => $canal->id)) }}" class="small">Auswählen</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

The generated URL in the form should look like this:

> /projects/71/canals/5103/damages

**[SOLUTION]Edit working code view.blade.php**

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('listDamages', $project->id, $canal->id), 'method' => 'get', 'class' =>'action-form')) }}
<button type="submit" href="{{ route('listDamages',array($project->id, $canal->id)) }}" class="small">Auswählen</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: `Route::get('/projects/{project_id}}/...` - extra `}` ?

Comment: Fixed it, but result stays the same :/

Comment: @lasagne You should not insert the solution into the question, but accept the answer that solves your problem, it would be clearer for future readers if they can spot at once the solution instead of having to catch the edit

Comment: Already done. Just had to wait 2 Minutes

Comment: I wasn't nagging you on it for the thick mark :), I expanded my comment above to explain myself better

Comment: You're right. I outlined the solution now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
echo Form::open(array('route' => array('listDamages', $project->id, $canal->id)));
```

Haven't tested the above though. Anyway, you can always build out the url, although you loose the benefit of the named route:

```
echo Form::open(array('url' => 'projects/'.$project->id.'/canals/'.$canal->id.'/damages'));
```